# Why does Mongodb update work but mongoose doesn't?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When I query monodb shell, I AM able to update the document.
This is the mongodb command I use:
`db.users.update({name:"bob"}, {$set: {email:"newEmail@gmail.com} })`

**But when I try to update it with mongoose, it doesn't work.
What am I missing??**

This is the code in mongoose:

// Create the users schema

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  email: String
}, {collection: "users"});
```

// Create a model

```
var userModel = mongoose.model("userModel", userSchema);
```

// Update a document

```
userModel.update({name:"bob"}, {$set: {email:"newEmail@gmail.com"}} );
```

Answer (score 1):

You should wait for the callback to see if the operation was succesful or not

```
userModel.update({ name: "bob" }, 
                 {$set: { email:"newEmail@gmail.com" }},
                 function (err, user) {
                     if (err) return handleError(err);
                     res.send(user);
                 });
```

The `mongoose` is working asynchronously, you should wait for the response in the callback. There is also a synchrone way to do that but With `node` is not recommended you will block the stack.

Comment: I didn't need any callback and saw in the documentation that it's an optional parameter so I just dropped it. But apparently it's required. Mongoose's docs needs some updating. Thank you good sir!

Comment: At least in this way you can see the result of the `update` operation, indeed it could be other issues but if there was an error you will see it in the console of your `node` instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this if you don't need the result in callback

```
userModel.update({name:"bob"}, {$set: {email:"newEmail@gmail.com"}}).exec();
```